# Will adding features pick up previously installed service pack updates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-pack

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 installed. Need to add a feature to the installation, Business Intelligence Development Studio. The question is do features installed after the application of a service pack pick up that service pack? If not does the service pack have to be installed again?

Comment: Thanks to Aaron and Spörri. This would be for non-production servers. But still need to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always err on the side of just installing the service pack again (it will know which components, if any, to update). Especially when adding client tools to a workstation - where this is not a major disruption. (And if you're adding BIDS to a production server, you should reconsider IMHO.)

Comment: Found this post after needing to do the same on SQL 2012. After installing the complete management tools, a dialog box popped up saying I need to install SP3 again

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reinstall the service pack, it will only update the feature you installed from source. (and I second Aarons humble option)